# Messages are not displayed in the exit_json() function in the custom Ansible module

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to figure out custom Ansible modules.
Messages are not displayed in the exit_json() function in the custom Ansible module

`library/test_out_module.py`

```
from ansible.module_utils.basic import AnsibleModule

def main():
    module = AnsibleModule(
        argument_spec=dict(
            some_var=dict(required=True, type='raw'),
        )
    )
    some_var = module.params['some_var']

    result = {}
    result['result_data'] = some_var
    result['result'] = 'goodbye'
    result['changed'] = True

    module.exit_json(**result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: test out module
      test_out_module:
        some_var: asdad
```

what am I doing wrong?

result

```
constantine@MacBook-Pro-Constantine ~/work/tapentertainment/ansible $ ./ansible-playbook playbooks/dev-devel.yml

PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [test out module] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Version:

```
ansible [core 2.16.3]
python version = 3.12.1 (main, Dec  7 2023, 20:45:44) [Clang 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)] 
jinja version = 3.1.3
libyaml = True
```

Comment: You’ll need to register and use a `debug` task like any other module: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables

Comment: Or run the playbook in verbose, to have the result of each module.

Comment: Right, that's the expected behavior. You may have a look into the example [Ansible Custom Module: How to "print" output?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75438687/6771046).

Comment: I know these methods. But they don't suit me. I need the module itself to be able to display information on the display. I see that some other modules can do this, but my knowledge in Python is not enough. Any ideas?

Comment: "_I need the module itself to be able to display information on the display._", please take note that modules are usually running on the Remote Node, whereby the "display" / stdout is on the Control Node. Therefore such is technically not implemented in Ansible. "_I see that some other modules can do this_", which would that be? Can you name some?

Comment: Please have also a look into: [Debug info from Ansible Custom Module?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54448411/6771046) or [How can I show progress for a long-running Ansible task?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42773566/6771046).